# C++11 `nullptr_t` returning function being elided?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

The following C++11 program doesn't output anything under gcc 4.7.2:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

decltype(nullptr) g()
{
    cout << "foo" << endl;
    return nullptr;
}

int* f()
{
    return g();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto x = f();
}
```

Is this correct behaviour, or is it a compiler bug?

**Update:**

Thanks guys.  FYI here is my workaround:

```
 struct NullPointer
 {
     template<class T> operator T*()
     {
          volatile decltype(nullptr) np = nullptr;
          return np;
     }
     operator bool()
     {
          volatile bool b = false;
          return b;
     }
 };

 NullPointer g() { return {}; }
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. 4.8.1 says ["foo".](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8448f4acd37eca8)

Comment: This has popped up at least once (and probably only once) on StackOverflow before, definitely a compiler bug.

Comment: Does the bug go away if you use `std::nullptr_t` in place of `decltype(nullptr)`?

Comment: @GManNickG: No, I was originally using it, just couldn't be bothered looking up which header it was defined in for the demo. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in G++ that discarded side-effects of expressions with type `nullptr_t`

It was fixed for G++ 4.7.4 and 4.8.0, see http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52988 for an initial incomplete fix and http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54170 for the complete fix.